# maximum how many items can use in oracle Apex single page

Tags: oracle-apex

Am using oracle apex 4.2. I have doubt whether maximum how many items can we use in a single pages. Now am using 100 to 110 item in single page.working fine no more issue regarding page processing slow lik that..if i had more w

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about database maintainance and physical implementation and so should be on dba

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In version 4.2 if the page item / page limit went from 100 to 200:

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/HTMDB/limits002.htm#HTMDB28632

Comment: am using 110 item and around 80 validation.if i go more than this facing issue..item not validating and value not retains..